# ActiveAdmin - Choose What Field Shows as Profile Name on Navigation/Menu Bar - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, controller, activeadmin

**Context**:
I am currently developing a web application in rails, and am using ActiveAdmin to manage admin functionalities. When signing into an Admin account, you have the ability to set the menu bar (navigation bar) title, menu tabs, and you can add a logout link.

On the top right of the menu bar, you will see your admin email (link to profile) and a logout link.

**The issue**:
I currently added a field called "full_name" to the admin model, and where the email use to show in the menu bar, it now tries to show "full_name" instead.

Is there a way to override what data field is shown in the menu bar for the current_user?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin looks for the presence of the following method in sequence to display the data

```
:display_name, :full_name, :name, :username, :login, :title, :email, :to_s
```

In your case you have added the `full_name` column, `full_name` field has a higher preference than the `email` field.

In your case, you can add `display_name` to the `AdminUser` model to override the value which you want to show.

```
def display_name
  email
end
```

If you want to add your custom method, then you can set `display_name_methods` config in the ActiveAdmin config file

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.display_name_methods = [:show_custom_name, :display_name, :to_s...]
  ...
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the help!